# Security exception calling DCOM service

Tags: windows, kerberos, windows-server-2012, windows-server-2019, dcom

We have .Net app running on a Windows Server 2019 VM that is attempting a DCOM call to a service running on Win Server 2012 in our quality assurance environment.  We are getting a security error:

System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80070721): Creating an instance of the COM component with CLSID {} from the IClassFactory failed due to the following error: 80070721 A security package specific error occurred. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070721).

We did some research and identified the following article: https://scomblogs.com/f/a-security-package-specific-error-occurred---runbook-designer

which said that changing HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System\Kerberos\Parameters\supportedencryptiontypes from 0x7ffffff8 to 0x7ffffffc resolves the issue.   We made this change on the Svr 2019 server and the call succeeded.   However our operations team is balking as this will require a change to group policy and allows for weak encryption methods so it is a no-op.

I looked in our Dev environment, where we have a similar configuration as in QA, and everything works fine.  I verified that the Kerberos supportedencryptiontypes is set to  0x7ffffff8 in Dev.  So this points to a configuration on the calling server and or the server hosting the DCOM service in our QA environment.  Can anyone provide any input on how to debug or troubleshoot this issue?  Thanks.